# Reset MySQL field to default value

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a command in MySQL to reset a field to its default value? You know, in favor of the "Do Not Repeat Yourself" rule, I don't want to write the (quite long) default value multiple times in code, only once in the DB.

I looked around quite some time in google, found nothing. I'm starting to suspect such command doesn't exist, but nevertheless, if it does, sy here's going to know about it. :)

Comment: Once changed, the database doesn't know the previous value.  What you can do is use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).  If you're not happy with the new value, you can `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: I mean the default value, not the initial value. It has to know that, its giving it automatically to every new row!

Comment: and no, I don't think tranzactions are what I'm looking for.

Comment: I understand your question now, and I think I got just the thing for you.  Check my answer! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MySQL has a `DEFAULT` [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) (and [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default)) that will do exactly what you want.

```
UPDATE table SET col = DEFAULT WHERE id = 2
```

OR

```
UPDATE table SET col = DEFAULT(col2) WHERE id = 3
```